# When to use passport.js?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I've been developing in node for the last months to try and understand the framework, and now I'm actually going to try to make an app for multiple devices.

I want to use a node project as the api, which will handle all post and get requests.

In another node project I would have a react web interface communicating with the node api with ajax and socket.io.

In a mobile android/ios or cordova I would have the mobile interface communicating as above.

Now that I've explained the background of my question I will describe my problem.

For now I have a node project that uses bcrypt to encrypt passwords for registration and login. I also use passport to establish a session and for flash messages.

```
router.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:'/', failureRedirect:'/users/login',failureFlash: true}),
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
    });

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        db_functions.getUserByEmail(username,function(error, results)  {
            if (error) throw error;

            bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password, function(err, res) {
                if(res === true){
                    return done(null,results[0])
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'})
                }
            });
        })
    }));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log(id)
    db_functions.getUserById(id,function(error, results)  {
        if (error) throw error;
        done(error,results[0])
    })
});
```

I read here http://passportjs.org/docs/overview, that if I'm going to use my node project as an API, I should disable sessions and I will therefore use:

```
app.get('/api/users/me',
  passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.json({ id: req.user.id, username: req.user.username });
  });
```

Now, that I have sessions disabled, why exactly should I keep using passport? I use bcrypt to register and check for password match when a user logs in. If I do remove it, does that mean that each request that comes from a web browser or a mobile device would have to also transmit the user and hashed password?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`passport` is an **authentication** library and sessions are a part of **authorization** — a different step in the process. You could use `passport` to issue a token such as a `jsonwebtoken`, instead of using sessions with a different library to verify those, such as `ejwt`, or create a middleware function to validate these tokens on routes which require authentication

`passport` is also extensible with a lot of plugins already developed to allow many forms of authentication to issue your authorization method.

You don't have to use it, it just makes it a bit easier. `bcrypt`, on the other hand, you probably have to use.

Comment: Thank you for making that clear. I read about jwt and I understand the subject better now.