# express-session vs passport.js?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am currently implementing email-password login functionality for a website using just express-session. Everywhere I look I see people using passport.js to authenticate requests. The below code is working for me.

```
app.post("/signup", function(req, res) {
    var user = new userModel(req.body);
    user.save();
    req.session.userid = user.id; // I use this id to authenticate
}
```

Do I have any reason to use passport?

Comment: You can read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927819/when-to-use-passport-js

Answer (score 1):

In NodeJS, you can authenticate in 2 ways:

1. Session-Based authentication
2. Token-Based authentication

Passport is a token-based authentication system. It uses JSON web token i.e jwt.

In your case, as you are using session-based authentication you need not use passport

Comment: Why do people use both session-based (cookie-session or express-session) and token-based (passport.js) together?

Comment: @vaibhavS You can check the link .. https://medium.com/@sherryhsu/session-vs-token-based-authentication-11a6c5ac45e4 hopefully you can get your answer.